# Two methods when implementing interface containing only one

Tags: java, generics, interface, type-erasure, java-bridge-method

I created interface `TwoMethods`. Source code:

```
interface TwoMethods<T>
{
    public void method(T t);
}
```

Then I created class implementing this interface and after disassembling I saw 2 methods.
Class:

```
class A implements TwoMethods<A>
{
    @Override
    public void method(A a) {}
}
```

After disassembling:

```
class A implements TwoMethods<A> {
   A();
   public void method(A); //first
   public void method(java.lang.Object); //second
}
```

Similarly for `Comparable` interface. Why when I create parametrized interface I have 2 methods. It is always, when I use parameter? I have additionally method with `Object` as argument?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we look at interface TwoMethods bytecode we will see that the actual method is

```
public abstract method(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

that is at bytecode level information about type parameter does not exist, type is erased, JVM simply does not know about generics, type parameters are replaced either with `Object` or in case if `T extends X` with `X`. So from the point of view of JVM

```
class A implements TwoMethods<A> {
    public void method(A a) {
        ...
```

`method(A a)` does not override interface method because in bytecode it is in `method(Object obj)` can override it. To fix this problem compiler builds an implicit method, so called bridge method, in class A

```
public void method(Object obj) {
     method((A)obj);
}
```

visible in bytecode only. Now for this code

```
A a = new A();
TwoMethods<A> tm = a;
tm.method(a);
```

compiler will replace `tm.method(a)` with call to the bridge

```
   INVOKEINTERFACE test/TwoMethods.method(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

and this will redirect the call to `A.method(A a);`

Answer (score 18):

`method(java.lang.Object)` is called the bridge method and it's generated because of type-erasure at compile time.

See [Effects of Type Erasure and Bridge Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)